# Pushing Mercurial commit to sourceforge with Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, mercurial, sourceforge

I've been using mercurial for my project on Sourceforge for a number of years just fine, but I've never been able to get a commit to push from inside of NetBeans. To write to the repo, sourceforge requires the url be formatted as (in my case) https://tambascot@hg.code.sf.net/p/soundboard/2.0.x but NetBeans always strips out the username portion of the URL, which leaves me with the read-only address of https://hg.code.sf.net/p/soundboard/2.0.x

Has anyone ever pushed to Mercurial on sourceforge from within NetBeans? Or am I stuck having to continue to do this from the command line?

Thanks